# Is there any difference between fusing and smashing particles?

Tags: fusion, particle-accelerators

**Fusion reaction**

In fusion process, a condition is required to allow the process to take place. Temperature (energy) + close contact (overcome coulomb barrier). The process normally observed inside of star. (nature)

**Smashing particles**

In particle collider, particles are being accelerated to close to speed of light (particle gains enormous energy) in both directions around the vacuum tunnels and then they will smash each other at some points when they are forced to cross path (close contact). The process usually produced in a controlled environment. (man-made)

**Question**

Is this a coincidence? or are they the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

In a Fusion Reaction, two disparate nuclei combine into a single, larger (stable) nucleus.

Example: `H + H => He`

In a Particle Collider / 'Smashing Particles', various charged particles collide at high velocities releasing energy and producing a variety of short lived particles and subatomic particles.

Example: `Au_nucleus + Au_nucleus => Energy + protons + neutrons + electrons + other subatomic particles`

Comment: Thanks for the examples, can you further elaborate the need for the conditions to obtain the results to contrast between the two processes?

Comment: In short how are the conditions different?

Comment: It is the difference between stable bound states and generation of new particles out of the excess energy, most of them unstable and certainly not one bound state.

Comment: In short, though perhaps not without some exceptions, the 'products' of Fusion will be more massive than its 'reactants'. The products of a Particle collider, if there are any stable products (it could in theory be 100% energy), are less massive than the 'reactants'.

Comment: Therefore it is the result that matters if products are stable it is fusion else they are simply colliding hard.

Comment: Some of us perform nuclear reactions using an accelerator at lower energies than in the LHC and get fission, fusion, and other expected reactions just fine. Nuclear energy states were originally mapped decades ago using accelerators. One example we do often is D(D,n)He3.

Comment: I'll point out that the example is incorrect, since He2 is decidedly short lived.  However, the key difference between 'simple' fusion reactions at relatively low center of mass energies, and things like the LHC, is the amount of energy and the total number of different pathways available for the energy and momentum to exit.

Comment: It is not just about stability. Two nuclei => hundreds of stable Hydrogen nuclei is still not fusion. Put simplistically, you're either combining nuclei (Fusion), splitting nuclei with neutrons (Fission). Smashing things together can do either of those, or neither (energy production, misses, breaking nucleii with momentum).

Comment: I was referring to stellar fusion with `H + H => He`, and did not specify the isotope. Or were you saying that the 'stable' qualifier is incorrect?